# How can I concatenate many iteration-extracted data values into a single function call?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

This is the ugliest thing I've ever written, but I just don't know a way to do this otherwise.
The issue is that I need to submit an SQL Query to a database that relies on information extracted from another location using iteration.

EG: I can extract the data with nested for loops, but then need to put an entire row back together to make an insert query for SQL. I tried temporarily storing the cell data in variables and doing it that way, but that also looked awful and didn't work.

Here is the code I am using now:

Please don't get mad. I know it's awful. I want to be better.
On a side note, I've taken to calling this line (line 98) the kiloline, because it's over 1000 characters long.

```
$res1 = pg_query("INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES ('" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" . 
    $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "')");
```

Please show me a better/more elegant/not asinine way to do this.

Comment: You know, newlines *totally* work inside SQL and between PHP concatenation operators.

Comment: Yea, yea they do...That would make it easier to read, at least...Oh between the operators...

Comment: So, that's easier to read, right? I think that works...

Comment: That is easier to read yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm going to try directly improving the assembly of this statement.  This might not completely answer your question, but it should at least push you down the right path.

```
$res1 = pg_query("INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES ('" . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "', '" 
    . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "')");
```

Now, doesn't that look better?  No?  Slightly more horrifying?  Sorry.

Assumption: You'll always call `getCellByColumnAndRow` with a number as the first parameter, it will always start with 1, and may end at any point.  Instead of building the SQL like *that*, use a loop to gather your data first...

```
$max = 12;
$values = array();
foreach(range(1, $max) as $index)
    $values[] = "'" . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($index, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "'";
```

Now you can just glue together the array.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES(' . join(', ', $values) .')';
```

Hmm.  `getFormattedValue` is SQL-safe, right?  What if it wasn't?

There's still some improvement to be made.  PostgreSQL supports [prepared statements](http://php.net/function.pg-prepare).  It might be wise to use them here.

Again, let's blindly assume that things are moderately dynamic.  PHP's PG extension uses a non-standard placeholder, which makes our life more difficult.  Let's make a small change to the data gathering:

```
$max = 12;
$values = array();
foreach(range(1, $max) as $index)
    $values[ '$' . $index ] = "'" . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($index, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "'";
```

The array is now keyed, using PG's prepared statement placeholders.

We'll now reassemble the SQL using the *keys* instead of the values:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES(' . join(', ', array_keys($values)) .')';
```

`$sql` now looks something like

```
INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES($1, $2, $3 ...);
```

Let's prepare and execute!

```
$sth = pg_prepare($dbh, '', $sql);
$res = pg_execute($dbh, '', array_values($values));
```

Prepared statements get us two things:

1. Added protection against SQL injection, and
2. Potential performance benefits when used in a loop.  Prepare once, execute multiple times.

Comment: So that is exactly what I needed to know - I was not aware that I could cut it into an array and then glue the array back together - I mean, now that you've said it of course it's obvious, but I would not have thought of that on my own. I really appreciate that =).

Comment: @Andrew, I've updated the answer with an additional option that you might find useful

Comment: I just need to do some reading on prepared statements and joining keyed arrays to go along with this and I think I'll have accomplished some learning this morning.

Comment: Be sure to review [Berry's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817762/168868) for another take on prepared statements.

Comment: I like all of this. Where can I learn more of these things? This is my first time using PHP and it seems pretty awesome.

Comment: Your go-to resource for *reference* material is the [official PHP manual](http://php.net/manual).  Read everything in the Language Reference, Security and Features sections, then *browse* through the Function Reference.  You aren't going to retain the vast majority of what you read, but it will give you a hint about what PHP can do and can't do, and what's easy and what's awkward.  You should read the [PHP tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) as well.  There's also a PHP [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) here on SO, with *lots* of smart people ... and some dunces.

Comment: Lurking in the PHP chat and [leafing through the top PHP questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=votes&pagesize=500) will be educational.  You'll eventually pick up terms, common design patterns, and, most horrifyingly of all, The PHP Way.  Oh, and one last thing before I go crash. There's a *huge* cultural bias in favor of MySQL in the PHP community.  If you love Postgres, you may find it infuriating.  Sorry about that, not our fault.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with an array and a loop to do it:

```
$values = array();
foreach (range(0, 12) as $i)
{
    $values[] = "'" . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i, $row)->getFormattedValue() . "'";
}
$values = implode(', ', $values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES ({$values})";
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple entries using iteration is not a strange requirement, and I wouldn't say that's ugly, per se. You do, however, seem to have a problem in security, as you don't escape the parameters.

I'm guessing prepared statements are actually what you are looking for. Otherwise, you could also use the `pg_query_params` to make it a bit cleaner (and much more secure!):

```
<?php
$statement = "INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES ( $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13 );";

pg_query_params( 
    $connection, 
    $statement, 
    array(
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, $row)->getFormattedValue(),
        $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12, $row)->getFormattedValue()
    )
);
```

As the values increment, you might want to have a little loop instead:

```
<?php
$statement = "INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES ( $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13 );";

for($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $values[] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i, $row)->getFormattedValue();
}


pg_query_params( $connection, $statement, $values );
```

*But*, I have to admit that this "smells" a bit. Perhaps you haven't normalised your database enough, or maybe the situation calls for it, but please do go over the schema again, you might have made a small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you complete the query with a loop? For example:

```
$query="INSERT INTO Project_Time_Sheet VALUES ('"; 
for($x=0; $x<$max;$x++){
    $query.=objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getFormattedValue()."'";
    if($x<($max-1)){
          $query.=", '";
    }
}

$query.="');"
```